Javascript settings not "sticking" when new page is opened (returns to default settings each time)
I'm pretty new to coding (have only taken one web design course where I learned basic HTML & CSS and we touched lightly on javascript/jquery but I still find Javascript pretty confusing).
I am trying to make a website where the user can customize certain things on the page (specifically the font that is displayed on the page, as well as the background-color and text color).
Based on what I learned in my web design class, I have managed to finagle a way for this to happen but each time a new page is opened, everything goes back to the page's default settings. I want the user to be able to press a button (customizing the page to their liking) and for this information to be "stored" so that when they open a new page, the settings that they chose remain (and they don't have to keep on pressing the same buttons to customize the page). I'm not sure if I'm going about this in the right way, because things get a little wonky- especially if you press one button and then press another button without first "toggling off" the first button that was clicked.
I've drafted up I've drafted up some sample lines of code to try and illustrate what I'm trying to do:


$("#font-selector").change(function() {
  // alert($(this).val());
  // $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
  $("body").removeClass();
  $("body").addClass($(this).val());
});

$(".color-change-1").click(
  function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("color-change-1");
  }
);

$(".color-change-2").click(
  function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("color-change-2");
  }
);
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open dyslexic';
  src: url('../fonts/opendyslexic-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/opendyslexic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: darkslategray;
}

body.serif {
  font-family: serif;
}

body.open-dyslexic {
  font-family: 'open dyslexic';
}

body.color-change-1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

body.color-change-2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="customize">
  <div class="font-selector">
    <label for="font-selector" class="select-font">Select font-     type:</label> <br>

    <select class="select-font-button" id="font-selector" autocomplete="off">

      <option selected="selected" value="sans-serif">sans serif</option>
      <option value="serif">serif</option>
      <option value="open-dyslexic">open dyslexic</option>

    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="color-change-1">
    <button class="light-mode-button">White background, <br> black text</button>
  </div>

  <div class="color-change-2">
    <button class="dark-mode-button">Black background, <br> white text</button>
  </div>

</div>




take a look into localstorage and how to get and set items in it

Not the easiest read for a beginner, but target the localstorage parts: MDN Web Storage API

Does this help/answer your question: Persist variables between page loads

Whenever the page is loaded, it starts from zero.  If you want any information to persist across page loads then you need to persist it somewhere.  You can use localStorage to store it in the user's browser.  Other options include having a server-side application where you store data in a database, or perhaps some third party service for storing data.  Either way, what you'd do is store whatever data you need to store when these settings change, and when loading the page you'd check the data for what settings to initially apply.

Since all your JavaScript is doing is setting styles, I would just suggest doing the work in CSS and then just linking each of your pages to that CSS file.
